# Please do not edit spam posts

Tags: discussion, support

Recently we also have an occasional spam post here. To better deal with this we need a short guide on what to do in case we stumple upon such a post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case we read a post we suspect to be spam we can rely on the fact that spammers are treated with no mercy on the StackExchange Network. This also includes rapid bans not only of a single user but if applicable also of the IP the user posted from.

This is done more or less automatically by the system without any intervention from us other than flagging a spam post as such.

To avoid unwanted auto-banning of an otherwise harmless user please only flag as spam when a post meets the criteria for spam:

[What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

To make sure the system spam hammer works at it's best we **should not edit spam**. More reasons why not to edit spam can be read in the following post:

[Should Spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited)

So in summary the fastest and most reliable way to get rid of spam is to only just **flag as spam**. Enough community spam-flags or a moderator intervention will vaporize both, spam and spammers pretty soon.

Comment: User with the same IP might get banned too? So all Users with dynamic IPs from their ISPs might get banned by chance? Great idea!